# Converting files

Tags: java, xml, docx, docx4j

is there'll be possible to convert from this .xml file to .docx programmaticaly in java, and backwards from .docx to .xml(with docx4j,or? how any samples)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><document>
<el Id="1">
    <text>Bestätigt wurde ich in meinem Studienwunsch während meines neunmonatigem Freiwilligendienstes in Thailand, als ich intensive Kontakte zu der chinesischen Minderheit hatte. Mein Interesse für die Kultur und Sprache Chinas haben sich dadurch noch verstärkt.</text>
</el>
<el Id="2">
    <text>Ich bin bilingual aufgewachsen (deutsch, portugiesisch Brasilien) und habe in der Schule weitere Sprachen erlernt, deshalb sehe ich es als eine gute Abrundung meiner Sprachkenntnisse an Chinesisch zu erlernen.</text>
</el>
<el Id="3">
    <text>Ich möchte durch den Bereich BWL mehr über die inneren Zusammenhänge und Abläufe in einem Unternehmen erfahren.</text>
</el>
<el Id="4">
    <text>Welchen Studienschwerpunkt ich später wählen werde, kann ich zum heutigen Zeitpunkt noch nicht sagen und werde dies erst später entscheiden.</text>
</el>
<el Id="5">
    <text>Ich stelle mir vor, dass ich nach Abschluss meines Studiums in einem international operierendem Unternehmen oder Organisation eine Tätigkeit finde, die meinem Profil entspricht. Beispielsweise könnte dies in den Bereichen Import/Export, Logistik oder in der Projektarbeit bei einer internationalen Organisation sein.</text>
</el>
<el Id="6">
    <text Id="6"/>
</el>
```

file in .docx format:

```
Bestätigt wurde ich in meinem Studienwunsch während meines neunmonatigem  Freiwilligendienstes in Thailand, als ich intensive Kontakte zu der chinesischen Minderheit  hatte. Mein Interesse für die Kultur und Sprache Chinas haben sich dadurch noch  verstärkt. Ich bin bilingual aufgewachsen (deutsch, portugiesisch Brasilien) und habe in  der Schule weitere Sprachen erlernt, deshalb sehe ich es als eine gute Abrundung meiner  Sprachkenntnisse an Chinesisch zu erlernen. Ich möchte durch den Bereich BWL mehr über die inneren Zusammenhänge und Abläufe in einem Unternehmen erfahren. Welchen Studienschwerpunkt ich später wählen werde, kann ich zum heutigen  Zeitpunkt noch nicht sagen und werde dies erst später entscheiden. Ich stelle mir vor, dass ich nach Abschluss meines Studiums in einem  international operierendem Unternehmen oder Organisation eine Tätigkeit finde, die meinem Profil entspricht. Beispielsweise könnte dies in den Bereichen Import/Export, Logistik oder  in der Projektarbeit bei einer internationalen Organisation sein.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three basic approaches for XML to docx:

1. parse your XML (using DOM or SAX); for each el element, create a
   w:p, and for each text element, create w:r/w:t
2. use XSLT to convert your XML to:

   - WordML, then use that as the main document part in a docx, OR
   - Flat Open XML, then convert the Flat Open XML to a docx
3. use the import XHTML stuff (XML + CSS)

Approach 3 is best if you have CSS for your XML, which you'd like reflected in your docx.

Whether you use approach 1 or 2 depends only on which you are more comfortable with.  With approach 1, all maintenance would be in Java.  With approach 2, some of your code is XSLT.

docx4j will facilitate which ever approach you'd prefer

Comment: 1.approach-is that suitable for arbitrary xml files? it can contain randomly text elements, user must choose the file then it will be converted in .docx file. Can you please give some example for how to create a w:p and w:r/w:t? Thank you

Comment: You'll need to make a new question for how to create a w:p and w:r/w:t.  It would also be nice if you voted this answer as helpful :-)

Answer (score 1):

A docx file is a collection of XML. You can, however, use Apache POI to create code that explores it and produces whatever format you need.